# Strongswan IPSec VPN tunnel with Public IP and no right subnet

Tags: vpn, ipsec, strongswan

I have to make VPN tunnel in which other party has sent me just their public IP(y.y.y.y) and no subnet. Am using Strongswan 5.3.5. I know the connection is possible is possible without rightsubnet thanks to [Possible to IPSec VPN Tunnel Public IP Addresses?](https://serverfault.com/questions/124462/possible-to-ipsec-vpn-tunnel-public-ip-addresses).

Phase 1 is set up but getting error in phase 2.

Error am getting is:

> parsed CREATE_CHILD_SA response 13 [ N(TS_UNACCEPT) ]    received
>   TS_UNACCEPTABLE notify, no CHILD_SA built

Below is my config

```
conn vpn-2
        left=192.168.0.5
        leftsubnet=192.168.0.0/28
        leftid=x.x.x.x
        right=y.y.y.y
        rightsubnet=%any
        rightid=%any
        keyexchange=ikev2
        ike=3des-md5-modp1024
        esp=aes256-sha1
        type=tunnel
```

Am still new to VPN connections but I've established one before which has rightsubnet but in this case, there is no right subnet. I've been stuck in this for days.

Comment: Did you try not removing _rightsubnet_? (Setting it to %any is definitely wrong, either set it to a specific address/subnet or to %dynamic.) In any case should you check the log and config of the other host if you receive such an error notify for the reason why it was returned.

Comment: Hi @ecdsa. Tried removing the subnet and also setting it as dynamic. None of them worked. Anyways I'll ask them to check it in their logs. Thanks for your input though.