# Tunelling public IP addresses in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, routing

I'm trying to setup a VPN to a data provider. They cannot route RFC1918 private addresses.

I believe that the situation is similar to [Possible to IPSec VPN Tunnel Public IP Addresses?](https://serverfault.com/questions/124462/possible-to-ipsec-vpn-tunnel-public-ip-addresses)

However, they also require that the VPN endpoint public address be different from the address connecting to their services.

If this was on-prem, I'd just have a route added that sends traffic for dataprovidernetwork/24 via the VPN.

We're in AWS though, and the IP addresses we get allocated are not from the same subnet. So I'm trying to work out how to have a client machine with a public IP of (e.g) 51.10.10.10 and a VPN server (e.g.) 18.10.10.10 and send all traffic from the client machine to the vendor network via the VPN server.

Is this a common pattern, and what's the right way to do this with something like OpenSWAN ?

Comment: Is the data provider recommending this VPN? This doesn’t sound common at all. Why aren’t you able to just use a tls/ssl connection?

Comment: It is being insisted on by the data provider, yeah. A simple sftp / https request would make more sense to me for sure, but that's apparently not an option.